# Creating list dependencies in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am attempting to create an excel workbook that will assist with Job Costing.
I have created a sheet with all of the lists I require, and have provided a name range to each list, ex "EmployeeName" "EmployeeSalary" "ProjectName" "ProjectNumber"
In a separate sheet, I have created a table with dropdowns

- one dropdown is Employee Name,
- and another is Project Name.

I am wanting to tie the **EmployeeSalary** to the **EmployeeName** in my table so that if I pick the employee's name from my dropdown, it auto populates a cell in the table with that employee's salary.
The same goes for the Project Number, I am wanting this to auto populate in a cell when I select a Project Name from my dropdown menu.
What is the formula that I would need to use?

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH

Answer (score 0):

Your employee salary list will need to have 2 columns. The first should be the name and the second the salary for that name. Note that you should keep the salary table sorted alphabetically by employee name.

Then you can use VLookup against the salary table using the employee name as the index and column number 2 as the return value.